# problem with multichat telegram bot aiogram

Tags: python, bots, telegram, aiogram

I have a problem related to the creation of a Telegram bot that will function in several chats at the same time.

One of the commands is the help request command. User uses /help {request text}. Then this text is sent to other chats with the same name

```
help_cb = CallbackData("help",'SenderId', "SenderName", 'action')
appeal_cb = CallbackData("appeal",'SenderId', 'action')

@dp.message_handler(commands="help")
async def help(message: types.Message):
    print("help")
    result = await db.check_if_allow(message.chat.id)
    if not result:
        await message.answer("Поки-що вам не дозволено відправляти запити про допогу. Спробуйте пізніше")
    else:
        if len(message.text) < 3:
            await message.answer("Опишіть вашу проблему детальніше.")
        else:
            forms, form = await db.get_chats_name(message.chat.id)
            await db.update_cooldown(message.chat.id)

            markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton(" Відповісти", callback_data=help_cb.new(SenderId = message.chat.id, SenderName = form[0],  action='answer')))
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("️ Видалити", callback_data=help_cb.new(SenderId = message.chat.id, SenderName = form[0], action='delete')))
            markup.add(InlineKeyboardButton("⛔ Поскаржитися", callback_data=help_cb.new(SenderId = message.chat.id, SenderName = form[0], action='appeal')))

            await message.answer("Запит на допомогу успішно надіслана")
            
            text = f"<b> Новий запит про допомогу!</b>\nКлас: {form[0]}\nЗапитання: {message.text}"

            for form in forms:
                await bot.send_message(form[0], text=text, reply_markup = markup)

            await AnswerState.helpInfo.set()
```

A "Reply" button is attached to the sent text. After clicking on it, the bot expects a reply in the form of a text that, after sending, is automatically forwarded to the chat that requested help.

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(help_cb.filter(action='answer'))
async def help_handler_answer(query: CallbackQuery, callback_data: dict, state: FSMContext):
    print("answer")
    await state.update_data(helpInfo = [callback_data["SenderId"], callback_data["SenderName"]])
    text = f"<b>Введіть відповідь на запитання</b>"
    await query.message.edit_reply_markup(None)
    await query.answer(text=text)
    await AnswerState.text.set()
```

```
@dp.message_handler(state=AnswerState.text)
async def process_title(message: Message, state: FSMContext):
    print("text")
    if len(message.text) < 3:
        await message.answer("В пояснені напишіть більше 2 слів.")
    else:
        await state.update_data(text = message.text)
        data = await state.get_data()

        await message.answer(f"<b>{data['helpInfo'][1]} щиро вдячний за допомогу!</b>")
        await state.finish()
        await bot.send_message(chat_id=data["helpInfo"][0], text=f"<b> Відповідь отримана!</b>\n\n{message.text}")
```

The problem is that after the chat that entered the command, it will not be able to use the bot functionality until another chat enters the same command.

Exemple:
[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwP5D.png)

I need either an explanation or an already fixed code that is causing the problem

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you are setting a state in the handler that handles /help command:

```
await AnswerState.helpInfo.set()
```

You don't actually need it, as I see.